# MS Access autocorrects html and displays p< as p<> in plain text memo field

Tags: ms-access-2010, autocorrect

Users enter statistical data into a MS Access database memo field that contains examples like this (p<0.001). For some reason Access displays this in the form or report as (p><0.001). It doesn't happen for the first example of p< in a memo field - only on the subsequent instances. This also causes any text after the final > not to be displayed on reports.

From what I can tell it is doing some strange autocorrect of html by attempting to complete the `<p>`!

Interestingly the data in the underlying table is correct. The field is formatted as plain text.

Does anyone have any thoughts on how to prevent this?

Thanks.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me, how are you entering the data in to the field? Directly on the database, a form, a OLEDB command?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have worked it out - it was copying from one field to another - the origna form field was plain text, the field it was copied to is rich text. I changed it to Plain text and now it is fine.